# Should I use `sudo` or `su` in a startup script?

Tags: linux, sudo, su, sysvinit

I have a personal program, that has a server/client design.

The server daemon part of it, should be run as its own limited user, and the program was not designed to drop its root privileges (if started as root) like some Linux programs do.

So my question, in its startup script in `/etc/init.d/`, should I use `sudo` or `su` to run this daemon as another user? Does it make a difference? Will either of the two even work? Something else?

The operating system is a custom GNU/Linux one, built using "Linux From Scratch" instructions, and does have both programs running correctly.

Comment: Do you have the source for server and client? You could add the uid dropping in case it was started as root.

Comment: yes, it's a python program. os.setuid is what i should do, right?

Comment: You could check if `os.getuid()` returns 0, then switch to another uid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can easily alter the program so that it drops its privileges, then this is the best approach. Switching user ID in the startup scripts is kludgey and rather inflexible, even if it does "work".

Comment: I ended up doing that. I figured i can use os.setuid, which is a far cleaner solution than using sudo or su.

Answer (score 3):

Of the two, I would use `su` for this purpose, because it is less configurable and therefore more predictable.  If you use `sudo` in your init script, and then (accidentally or purposefully) remove the `root ALL=(ALL) ALL` entry in `/etc/sudoers`, your init script will mysteriously break.

Furthermore, I would use the following form to reduce the configuration footprint even further:

```
su -s /bin/sh -c "my_program my_args etc" my_user
```

The `-s` option means you can change the user's default shell to /bin/false or /sbin/nologin or something without breaking the script.  You might also want to redirect the standard I/O to `/dev/null` or some other suitable place, if your program doesn't already handle that itself.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of convenience I suggest you to look at [chpst](http://smarden.org/runit/chpst.8.html) program from runit supervisor stack. It's very convenient and saves one from messing with command line parameter escaping etc. which is a pain with `sudo`/`su`.

If you want to run program as another user you call it just like that:

```
chpst -u my_user /path/to/program
```

It does `setsid`, `setgid`, `execve` on your program, that's all (it have a lot other nice features).

If your distribution includes [busybox](http://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html), you also can check if it has `chpst` applet compiled, you may already have it and don't need separate package.

Comment: `chpst` sets only uid ang gid and eventually environment variables for UID and GID. It won't set up the whole shell environment for you as expected (eg $HOME ...).

Answer (score 2):

Technically, both should work fine, however you probably want to follow convention here. Sudo is generally used to elevate to root to run a single command, while su is generally used to change to a new user and then run commands as that new user:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo
- http://www.sudo.ws/

That said, there are a few views on sudo vs su if you do a quick Google search:

- http://www.tuxmagazine.com/node/1000148
- http://www.serverschool.com/operating-systems/sudo-vs-su-what-really-matters/
- http://maketecheasier.com/sudo-vs-su-linux-mte-explains/2012/04/24

Comment: Actually `su` is usually used for becoming another user while `sudo` is used for executing ad hoc commands as another user. `su -c` is the (rough) equivalent of `sudo` and `sudo -s` is the equivalent of `su`. Contrary to popular belief the "su" in either command stands for "switch user" not "super user". They are both for switching to *any* user, but both default to root.

Comment: Agreed. I was simply stating what I've seen used as convention on most Linux/Unix in the past; sudo generally for a single root based command while su more generally to execute as another user.

Comment: Sudo can break init scripts if `requiretty` is enabled in /etc/sudoers (on by default in cent 6, cent 7, fedora)https://github.com/influxdb/influxdb/issues/800